# Find a value in an array of populated objects mongdb - lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Maybe this question is duplicate or asked several times in different ways but still haven't solved my problem. I am creating nodejs api returning 10,000 populated objects from mongodb. I want to filter array based on the object.

```
{color: red}
```

How can i use lodash filter to return array with containing specified filter object.

```
[
  {
    "value": 200,
    "newEle": {
      "gradient": "true",
      "mode": {
        "color": "red"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "value": 100,
    "newEle": {
      "gradient": "false",
      "mode": {
        "color": "blue"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: _return array with containing specified filter object._ At _**specific**_ path or at any nesting level?

Comment: @hindmost I want array with specified filter object but by using object `{color: red}` as filter parameter.

Comment: What I meant is: should a matching object be at specific path (like `.newEle.mode` in your sample) or arbitrary path?

Comment: @hindmost yes, specific path `.newEle.mode`

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifically trying to filter by just the color you can use vanilla JS's `.filter()` to get all the objects with the `color` property of `red` into a new array:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "value": 200,
    "newEle": {
      "gradient": "true",
      "mode": {
        "color": "red"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "value": 100,
    "newEle": {
      "gradient": "false",
      "mode": {
        "color": "blue"
      }
    }
  }
],
color = "red",
res = arr.filter(obj => obj.newEle.mode.color === color);

console.log(res);
```

If you wish to use `lodash` specifically you can use `_.filter()`:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    "value": 200,
    "newEle": {
      "gradient": "true",
      "mode": {
        "color": "red"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "value": 100,
    "newEle": {
      "gradient": "false",
      "mode": {
        "color": "blue"
      }
    }
  }
],
color = "red",
res = _.filter(arr, obj => obj.newEle.mode.color === color);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: what if i want to use the object itself `{color: red}`

Answer (score 0):

When using lodash, it's as simple as this.

```
 let filtered_array = _.filter(myArr, { color: 'red' });
```

However, since you have nested nested objects, you'd want to create a predicate that accesses the nested value. You do this with an array.

```
 let filtered_array = _.filter(myArr, ['newEle.mode.color', 'red']);
```